# Is a Yongnuo 50mm f/1.8f F-mount lens compatible with Nikon F55 or Nikon F80 film SLRs?

Tags: lens, nikon, lens-mount, compatibility, third-party

I have a Yongnuo 50mm f/1.8N (AF/MF) lens that I use with my Nikon D5600 DSLR (aps-c). I'd like to buy a Nikon SLR film camera, an F55 or F80, and use it with this Yongnuo lens. What issues will I face, if any?

Answer (score 3):

Without actually having tried, I would assume no issues at all.

Your Yongnuo lens is comparable (from a technical viewpoint) with the Nikon AF-S series of lenses and these are fully compatible with both the F55 and the F80.